# Unable send data from backend(nodejs) to frontend(angular2)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, elasticsearch

I have some data which I queried from elasticsearch through nodejs and I want to send those to frontend. When I try to do that it shows me an error as below.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null
at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
at zone.js:709
at rejected (messages-component.js:14)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.ts:296)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
at Zone.run (zone.js:141)
at zone.js:831
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:288)
```

Back-end looks like this,

```
var name = ".class";

rama();

function rama() {
'use strict';

const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: '127.0.0.1:9200',
  log: 'error'
});

const search = function search(index, body) {
  return esClient.search({index: index, body: body});
};

const test = function test() {
  let body = {
    size: 20,
    from: 0,
    query: {
      match: {
        JarFileName: {
          query: 'CambioClient.jar'
        }
      }
    }
  };
  search('clsdex', body)
  .then(results => {
    results.hits.hits.forEach((hit, index) => name="Test");
  })
  .catch(console.error);
};

test();
};

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var messages = [{text: name, owner: 'Tim'},{text: 'other message', owner:'Jane'}];

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
next();
})

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
res.json(messages);
})

app.listen(11500);
```

This is the part in front-end(message-component.ts) where I receiving the results,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { WebService } from './web.service';

@Component({
selector: 'messages',
template: `
<div *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <md-card style="margin:8px">
        <md-card-title>{{message.owner}}</md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>{{message.text}}</md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</div>
`
})
export class MessagesComponent {

messages = [];

constructor(private webService: WebService) {}

async ngOnInit() {
    var response = await this.webService.getMessages();
    this.messages = response.json();
}
}
```

Where am I mistaken this? Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Can you try `this.webService.getMessages().subscribe((res)=> this.messages = res.json());`?

Comment: Where should I try that?

Comment: Inside `ngOnInit`

Comment: Can't use inside ngOnInit, it shows `[ts] Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<Response>'.`

Comment: Then change subscribe with `then`. I really suggest you to read the documentation on http module: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: Okay, I will look in to that.

Comment: I have tried `this.webService.getMessages().subscribe((res)=> this.messages = res.json());` as you said, Now it doesn't shows any errors but the name variable doesn't get initialized with the result I want. I have printed out and checked classNames are printed as I want but it didn't initialize name variable. What is wrong there?

Comment: What is the name variable? I only see the messages variable in your code

Comment: The first variable in the back-end code. `var name = ".class";` I am trying to initialize it to "Test", just for test it now.

Comment: Solved it, thank you for your time.